# Differential equation with a perturbation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not sure why a proportionality symbol has appeared in the working below. Is it a typo by any chance?

[image]

Comment: Not a typo... but the phrasing is atrocious. (1.5) should read $$N'(t)=n'(t)\quad f(N(t))\approx f(N^*)+n(t)f'(N^*)=n(t)f'(N^*)\implies n'(t)\approx n(t)f'(N^*)$$ which implies that $n(t)$ is approximately proportional to $$\exp\left(f'(N^*)t\right),$$ in a weak sense (and one would need more work to make precise the weak sense in which this approximate proportionality holds).

Comment: Could you explain why it is approximately proportional to and not approximately equal to?

Comment: Because $x'(t)=ax(t)$ does not imply $x(t)=e^{at}$, does it?

Comment: By the way, what is your source?

Comment: Mathematical Biology 1 An Introduction JD Murray

Comment: Hmmm... At least this page from the book could benefit from a more precise writing, I am afraid.